# Routing to a different AWS region using Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, cname-record, amazon-route53

I have a domain : example.com hosted in AWS using Route 53

It has the following Record set

- A: Alias
- AAAA: Alias
- MX: [..]
- NS: [..]
- SOA [..]
- CNAME: *.example.com

The Alias is pointed to an elastic bean stalk in the US region.

My requirement is to have a site - alpha.example.com but this should point to an Elastic bean stalk in the *UK* region. In effect, access to **www.example.com** should go to *US* region and **alpha.example.com** needs to go to UK region. I need to consider that in future if I need **beta.example.com** to go to an elastic beans stalk in *Singapore* region, this should be possible as well.

- Is this possible - How can I do it?
- Is it a mistake to give CNAME: *.example.com and I am hoping I would need to change that?

Comment: This [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/latency-based-multi-region-routing-now-available-for-aws/) and [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html) would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcard records in Route 53 only apply when a more specific record is not present.

Just create the records you need.

`alpha.example.com` would only match `*.example.com` when there is no record for `alpha.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks, I manage to do this by pointing DNS to CNAME - simple.